# SSRS - Use Macro in an SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, macros

is it possible to have a macro on an SSRS Report that is exported in Excel format ?

We need to rename the sheet based on content of the report a user is viewing.

For ex: 'SalesReport' shows data for California - so sheet name might be 'California sales';
'SalesReport' shows data for New York - so sheet name might be 'New York sales';

This update can happen when user clicks on the worksheet.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure that adding a macro is impossible without some sort of .xls post-processing.

If you want to rename a sheet you will also need some post-processing.  This is something that lots of people want and from reading msdn it sounds like it's likely to be included in a future SSRS version.

And if you *really* want to rename a sheet here's one solution: http://spacefold.com/lisa/post/2007/10/03/Changing-the-Sheet-names-in-SQL-Server-RS-Excel-QnD-XSLT.aspx

Comment: I have seen that article before but it seemed like a lot of work for a simple task. 
Another option was to distribute the macro to users for post processing.